# Frameworks version number in plist are changed by XCode 13 when app is published on apple store or testFlight

Tags: ios, xcode, testflight, xcode13

I use a self made framework with its version number set in the info.plist file. It corresponds to the field "Bundle version string" or CFBundleShortVersionString.

When I publish an app on testFlight with XCode 13, I've noticed the version number of my framework is changed to the value corresponding to the version of the app. For instance, If the version of the app is X.X.X, and the version number of the framework is Y.Y.Y. After publishing, when I install the app from testFlight, the version number of the framework is changed from Y.Y.Y to X.X.X.

I'm pretty sure the change is done during the upload since if I install the app directly from XCode to my iphone, the version number of the framework is not changed.

I did a test with XCode 12 and I don't have this behavior. That means it's a change done in XCode 13.

It's an issue for me, because I use the framework version number in my code logic.
Is there any way to disable this behavior?

Answer (score 6):

I've found the answer. Unselect the option “Manage Version and Build Number" when you upload the app.

[image: Upload options for XCode 13]